# Python scraping google finance

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape stock prices from google finance's [new interface](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/AAPL:NASDAQ).
I am using `xpath` to navigate to the location of the price, but upon printing it, it always returns a pair of square braces `[]`.

I have tried fixing it but nothing seems to work, and it also does this for all of the other objects on the screen.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import time

def parse(ticker):
    url = "http://google.com/finance?q=%s"%(ticker)
    response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    parser = html.fromstring(response.content)
    priceO = parser.xpath('//*[@id="fac-ut"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/span[1]/text()')
    print priceO
parse('AAPL')
```

Output:

```
[]

[Finished in 1.2s]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath seem to be incorrect

Try to replace

```
priceO = parser.xpath('//*[@id="fac-ut"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/span[1]/text()')
```

with below line

```
price0 = parser.xpath('//div[@id="price-panel"]//span')[0].text_content().strip()
```

*output:*

```
172.50
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a question though, how did you get that xpath? If you try to get it by inspecting element, it gives the one I have in my question.

Comment: I don't use selectors generated by browser built-in tools - just created my own. Note that XPath is not something unique - there might be dozens of different ways to match same node using XPath...

Comment: @an I'm going to put your 'I don't use selectors...' stack comment into my instructional python code snippet as a comment. :) I ran across Xpath recently and finally scratched my head and just 'GOT IT WORKING' anyhow anyway. Now I don't feel guilty.

Comment: I have a question. How did you create that path? I can't find "price-panel" in the html of the site.

Comment: I just realized that you have used finance.google.com. I am trying to extract the data from  google.com/finance because in a few weeks the other website will be deprecated.

Comment: Oh.. :) I see. Can you access http://google.com/finance/?q=AAPL? I got 404 status code...

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it like this?

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import datetime
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn import metrics
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from sklearn import cluster, covariance, manifold

start = '2019-02-01'
end = '2020-02-01'

tickers = ['MMM',
'ABT',
'ABBV',
'ABMD',
'ACN',
'ATVI']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Open','Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Open', 'Adj Close']])

#names = np.reshape(price_data, (len(price_data), 1))

names = pd.concat(price_data)
names.reset_index()

#pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

open = np.array([q['Open'] for q in price_data]).astype(np.float)
close = np.array([q['Adj Close'] for q in price_data]).astype(np.float)


print(names)
```

[image]

Comment: Gives: ImmediateDeprecationError: 
Google finance has been immediately deprecated due to large breaks in the API without the
introduction of a stable replacement. Pull Requests to re-enable these data
connectors are welcome.

Comment: Apparently that other services was shut down.  I just updated my original answer.  Use the update and it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

| Problem (besides wrong XPath) | Solution |
| --- | --- |
| No [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) in request headers. Default `requests` `user-agent` is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) so Google understand that it's a script. | [Check what's your `user-angent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent). Pass `user-agent` to [request headers](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers). |

You can also try to use [`parsel`](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/) with CSS selectors since it might be a bit easier and it [translates every CSS selector query to XPath under the hood](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/blob/b479b1822b0a61452a341dc7806a1cc34278ba1c/parsel/selector.py#L344-L355).

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/web-scraping-from-google-finance-returned-data-list-always-e#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, json
from itertools import zip_longest


def scrape_google_finance(ticker: str):
    # https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
    params = {
        "hl": "en" # language
        }

    # https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
    # https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36",
        }

    html = requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/finance/quote/{ticker}", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    
    ticker_data = {"right_panel_data": {},
                    "ticker_info": {}}
    
    ticker_data["ticker_info"]["title"] = soup.select_one(".zzDege").text
    ticker_data["ticker_info"]["current_price"] = soup.select_one(".AHmHk .fxKbKc").text
    
    right_panel_keys = soup.select(".gyFHrc .mfs7Fc")
    right_panel_values = soup.select(".gyFHrc .P6K39c")
    
    for key, value in zip_longest(right_panel_keys, right_panel_values):
        key_value = key.text.lower().replace(" ", "_")

        ticker_data["right_panel_data"][key_value] = value.text
    
    return ticker_data
    

data = scrape_google_finance(ticker="GOOGL:NASDAQ")

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
{
  "right_panel_data": {
    "previous_close": "$2,803.01",
    "day_range": "$2,806.21 - $2,874.24",
    "year_range": "$2,091.43 - $3,030.93",
    "market_cap": "1.89T USD",
    "volume": "1.68M",
    "p/e_ratio": "25.49",
    "dividend_yield": "-",
    "primary_exchange": "NASDAQ",
    "ceo": "Sundar Pichai",
    "founded": "Oct 2, 2015",
    "headquarters": "Mountain View, CaliforniaUnited States",
    "website": "abc.xyz",
    "employees": "156,500"
  },
  "ticker_info": {
    "title": "Alphabet Inc Class A",
    "current_price": "$2,859.43"
  }
}
```

If you want to scrape more data with a line-by-line explanation, there's a [Scrape Google Finance Ticker Quote Data in Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-finance-ticker-quote-data-in-python/#what_will_be_scraped) blog post of mine that also covers scraping time-series data using Nasdaq API.